# IPackageFragment not open when trying to get IPackageFragment with pacakge name

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

With below code i am trying to get IPackageFragment element for a given package name. But toString() of the IPackageFragment returned is com.abc.def (not open). 
Because of this when I try to access methods of all classes in this package I get JavaModelException.

Note: I can open and view the java files in this package in eclipse. Could anyone please tell what is wrong with this package.

```
private IPackageFragment getPackage(String name)
  throws Exception
{
  IPackageFragmentRoot[] roots = project.getAllPackageFragmentRoots();
  for (int ii = 0; ii < roots.length; ii++){
    IPackageFragment fragment = roots[ii].getPackageFragment(name);
    if(fragment != null && fragment.exists()){
      return fragment;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Package fragments elements need to be opened before they can be navigated or manipulated. You need to call open() on the package fragment before you can access the elements in the package fragment.